# Image uploading in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to upload image with some other para meters to the server .I tried a lot but i am unable to do it .Please help me to do it.

**My json url** : https://www.zdoof.com/api/zTimeline/insert_post

**parameter** : "Is_checkin", "Description", "Videolink", "Post_image", "Created_by", "Created_on"

**my code :**

func jsonToUpload() {
        let image = UIImage.init(named:"IMG_1114.JPG")

```
        print("Tapan")

    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.2)!


    let param=[
        "Is_checkin" : "0",
        "Description" : self.cookingText.text!,
       "Videolink" : "",
        "Post_image" : "",
        "Created_by" : "4490",
        "Created_on" : "23/Sept/2017"


        ]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in param{
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    },
                     to:"https://www.zdoof.com/api/zTimeline/insert_post")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value!)  
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)  
        }
    }
}
```

**My Another code :**

func myImageUploadRequest()
    {

```
    let postPictureUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.zdoof.com/api/zTimeline/insert_post")
```

//         let Params = scriptUrl + "Created_by=(4490)" + "&Created_on=01/jan/2017" + "&Is_checkin=0" + "Description=(self.cookingText.text!)" + "Post_image=(myImage.image)"

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: postPictureUrl! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let param=[
        "Is_checkin" : "0",
        "Description" : self.cookingText.text!,
       "Videolink" : "",
        "Post_image" : "" ,
        "Created_by" : "4490",
        "Created_on" : "20/Sept/2017"

        //            "mer_type": "smalll"
        ]




    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")


  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage.image!, 1)
    print(imageData!)

    if(imageData==nil)  { return; }
```

//        let imageStr = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options:.endLineWithCarriageReturn)

```
    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("******* response = \(String(describing: response))")

        // Print out reponse body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary

            print(json!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                self.myImage.image = nil;
            });

        }catch
        {
            print(error)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}


func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        }
    }

    let filename = "user-profile.jpg"
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)



    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    return body
}



func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}
```

extension NSMutableData {

```
func appendString(string: String) {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    append(data!)
}
```

Comment: is your issue solved now ?

Comment: Try setting the parameters **before** setting the file 

        `for (key, value) in param{
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }


multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")`